# Managing personal libraries in C

Tags: c, git, module

Over the years, I have accumulated code that is common in my projects and have decided to split it into libraries for easier reuse.

Until recently, I was content with just copying over the needed files into my current project, but that starts getting inefficient; I have to include the source for these libraries in each git project and if I find a bug, I have to update all projects using the buggy code.

Searching around, it seems like `git submodules` might be a solution. Are there any other alternatives? I imagine it is common for programmers to have these "personal libraries". How do you manage them?

Comment: I just have a recursive makefile setup that builds all the libraries in a specific order, then just copies them all to a common staging area defined by an environment variable inherited by the makefiles. Other projects (apps, services, etc), use the same environment variable to import the libraries from the staging area. This solution relies strictly on GNU make and shell environment variables.

Comment: Build a library. Install it in `/usr/local/lib` or `$HOME/lib` or `$HOME/$(uname -m)/lib`.  Link against it.

Comment: The problem is, what do you do when you want to distribute a project that uses one or more of your libraries. Do you include the static libraries, or do you ask those interested to download them?

Comment: Consider using `git subtree` instead of `submodule`. Makes checking out your project and working with the `sub` project a lot cleaner.